# Qt wrongly thinks QImage is loaded properly

Tags: c++, qt, memory, heap-memory, qimage

I am having an issue when trying to store a sequence of image data with Qt.

Here is a piece of code that shows the problem:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <QImage>

...

const int nFrames = 1000;
std::vector<int> sizes(nFrames);
std::vector<uchar*> images(nFrames);
for (int k = 0; k < nFrames; k++)
{
    QImage *img = new QImage("/.../sample.png");
    uchar *data = img->bits();
    sizes.at(k) = img->width() * img->height();
    images.at(k) = data;
}

std::cout << "Data loaded \"successfully\"." << std::endl;

for (int k = 0; k < nFrames; k++)
{
    std::cout << k << ": " << (int) (images.at(k)[0]) << std::endl;
}
```

In the first loop, the program loads QImage objects and puts the bitmaps in the `images` vector of pointers. In the second loop, we just read a pixel of each frame.

The problem is that the program proceeds through the first loop without complaining, even if the heap memory becomes full. As a result, I get a crash in the second loop, as shown by the output of the program:

```
Data loaded "successfully".
0: 128
1: 128
2: 128
...
192: 128
[crash before hitting 1000]
```

To reproduce the problem, you can use the grayscale image below, and you may need to change the value of `nFrames`, depending on how much memory you have.

**My question is:** How can I load the data in the first loop in a way that would allow me to detect if the memory becomes full? I don't necessarily need to keep the QImage objects in memory, but only the data of the`images` vector.

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Btw, it is not necessary to create `QImage` on heap. It supports COW.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, the first loop has memory leak becouse of `img` objects are not deleted.

From Qt documentation:

> uchar * QImage::bits()
>
> Returns a pointer to the first pixel data. This
>   is equivalent to scanLine(0).
>
> Note that QImage uses implicit data sharing. This function performs a
>   deep copy of the shared pixel data, thus ensuring that this QImage is
>   the only one using the current return value.

So you can safely delete `img` at and of loop.

```
    ....
    images.at(k) = data;
    delete img;
}
```

To detect if the memory becomes full you can check if operator `new` create `QImage` object like this:

```
QImage *img = new QImage("/.../sample.png");
if(!img) {
    //out of memory
}
```

Comment: You cannot ``delete img``, as the pointers stored in ``images`` would then point to nowhere and make the second loop crash.

Comment: Also, the ``if (!img)`` does not catch the memory issue. Does this code work for you? I tried on Debian.

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:**

The first loop can be replaced by the following:

```
for (int k = 0; k < nFrames; k++)
{
    QImage *img = new QImage("/.../sample.png");
    sizes.at(k) = img->width() * img->height();
    uchar *data = new uchar[sizes.at(k)];
    std::copy(img->bits(), img->bits() + sizes.at(k), data);
    images.at(k) = data;
    delete img;
}
```

This creates in `images.at(k)` a copy of the data that `img->bits()` points to. (Btw, this allows now to delete the `QImage` at the end of the first for loop.) An std::bad_alloc error in the loop if out of memory.

**However, this is not good enough.** I suspect possible issues when `nFrames` is set to a value such that the maximum memory taken by the program is close to the limit (or when another program frees memory while this is running). **My concern is that I still have no guarantee that `img.bits()` returns a pointer to accurate data.**